Twilio Group Text appears as 2-way conversation on device
I am using the Twilio conversations demo app https://github.com/twilio/twilio-conversations-demo-react to explore the Conversations API and more specifically group texting capability.  According to the documentation, https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/group-texting, I should be able to set up a group chat where each participant is individually identified.
This does not work.  At least in the demo app.  I setup a conversation with 2 users (from 2 separate proxy numbers) and 2 external numbers: one iOS device and one Android device.  Then I sent a message from each chat participant.  From the 1st demo app it looks like this...

Looks good!  Each participant is identifiable.  Likewise for the 2nd demo app...

On the devices it is a different story.  Here is the Andriod device...

Here is the iOS device...

So for the Android and iOS devices it is simply a 2-way chat.  The participants are not identified.  This is simply not a group text experience.  This issue seems to be a fundamental limitation of the Conversations Group Text feature.
Or perhaps I am missing something basic?  I am not using projected address numbers because the demo app does not support them, but I don't think that would make a difference.  I am using 2 separate proxy numbers for the users.
So how do I enable a group chat experience in Android or iOS such as users are accustomed to?
